# error failure reading sector 0x311689a0 from 'hd1'. ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, reboot

This is the error I got after installing Ubuntu on a Asus X551M.

I installed​ 14.04 forever ago and had it dual boot with Windows 10, then I removed Linux and after a while my Windows 10 became crap as always.

So I decided to install Ubuntu and delete Windows 10. Now I got this error. I have it on a USB, I used Rufus, and I tried the GTP and even tried doing the DD Image as well as the ISO. Neither worked. I tried the 64bit. 
I am not very experienced in Ubuntu. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same error. It should be due to one of the following reason: i) bad sector; ii) broken hdd cable. Try to change the hdd/ssd or replace the hdd cable.